# How to load *.mjpg file to dlib

Tags: c++, dlib

I am new on dlib. I want to use the example "Landmark Detection" from dlib in C++, but I want to use it with an `*.mjpg` file instead of an simple image. I don't know how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract video frames as images before loading them into dlib.

[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) makes that pretty easy:
`ffmpeg -i video_file.mjpg image_directory/frame%d.jpg`

This will extract all of the frames from `video_file.mjpg` as JPEGs and save them in `image_directory/`.  You can then use these frames to train and test dlib.